# Output mysql as raw text

Tags: php, mysql

I have a result in the database like this

```
[border color=#EEE]
    [pictitle]Title of your picture[/pictitle]
    [image]http://tingle.fm/wiki/assets/images/default-thumb.gif[/image]
    [line color=#D4D4D4][/line]
[/border]
```

And for some reason when I output the text it shows like this:

```
[border color=#EEE]
[pictitle]Title of your picture[/pictitle]
[image]http://tingle.fm/wiki/assets/images/default-thumb.gif[/image]
gif[/image]
[line color=#D4D4D4][/line]
[/border]
```

The code I use is this:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT FROM wiki WHERE id='1'");
$assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
echo nl2br($assoc['content']);
?>
```

Is there any way I can output the text as raw please so it indents? Much appreciated!

Comment: Wrap in `<pre>` tags?  Won't need `nl2br` either.

Comment: I can't use <pre> becasue I'm using a diff to compare 2 different variables and when I include pre it shows in the edit.

Comment: The output you have provided - is it what you see on page or is it source code?

Comment: If they are tabs then `str_replace("\t", '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');` if spaces then replace space with `&nbsp;`. You won't see whitespace (tabs, spaces, newline, etc) in the browser.

Comment: it's what I see on the page

Answer (score 0):

If this is the output on your page, then make sure you can see those spaces/tabs also in the source code. If you can, then you can use `str_replace` to replace those white characters with something that will be also visible on the page

```
// Replacing white space characters with HTML entities
$replacedSpaces = str_replace("\n    ", "\n&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", $assoc['content']);

// Replacing new line characters with <br> and printing it out
echo nl2br($replacedSpaces);
```